# Search tool for big list on amazon.com?

Tags: amazon

I have a list of 10600 book titles which I would like to find on amazon.com to make an estimate of how much the total value of all the books would be.

Is there any software that could help me with the searching of the book titles and compiling all the prices from Amazon to a total sum?

Comment: "`how much the total value of all the books would be`"  - do you mean the cost?

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a software for you, but maybe this will help you anyway.

You could use the MWS API and look for some plugins or write it yourself:
https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/docs.html

Or you can use the Amazon to Excel Tool. You will also need a MWS developer account:
https://www.sellertools.io/